Image Authenticaion
I have a NestJS application that servers images which requires authentication. For my authentication I'm using JWT however when I want to display the image in an img tag I cannot attach the Authorization header to the GET request. I've read some articles about how to authenticate files, some recommended Signed Url but did not really show how exactly it should be implemented.
I use NestJS for the backend API and MINIO for my datastore.

I wonder if this is a duplicate of: Authorization header in img src link

To serve authenticated images in your NestJS application, you can utilize Signed URLs with Minio. Signed URLs allow temporary access to resources without the need for an Authorization header, making them suitable for scenarios like serving images in  tags.
// Image controller to generate signed URLs
@Controller('images')
export class ImageController {
  constructor(private imageService: ImageService) {}

  @Get(':filename')
  @UseGuards(AuthGuard()) // Protect route with authentication
  async getImage(@Param('filename') filename: string, @Req() req: Request) {
    try {
      const signedUrl = await this.imageService.generateSignedUrl(filename, req.user);
      return { signedUrl };
    } catch (error) {
      // Handle error
    }
  }
}

// Image service to generate signed URLs
@Injectable()
export class ImageService {
  constructor(private minioClient: MinioClient) {}

  async generateSignedUrl(filename: string, user: any): Promise<string> {
    // Logic to generate signed URL for the image based on filename and user
    // Use Minio SDK to generate signed URL
    // Example:
    // const signedUrl = await this.minioClient.presignedGetObject('bucketName', filename);
    return signedUrl;
  }
}

Implementation exmple:
<img src="signedUrlFromBackend" alt="Image" />


To prevent making a second data fetch request within the useEffect, we first instantiate a useRef called isDataFetched with an initial value of false. Then, we wrap the execution of the fetch request within an if condition that checks if isDataFetched.current is false. If it is, we execute the fetch request, update the data state, and change the value of isDataFetched.current to true after completing the request.
